# Sequelize doesn't connect to database

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, plesk

Im trying to connect to a db using sequelize, but it doesnt work. But I don't get an error message either.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/plesk ', {
  dialectOptions: {
    charset: 'utf8'
  },
  logging: console.log
})

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

This is the code I use (obviously user and password are different) and I never gets to the catch nor to the then part.

Comment: If you put  `console.log('connecting')` right before the sequelize call, do you see it?

Comment: Yeah, it also executes code after the sequelize call, it seems like it never resolves the promise or something like that. Also the exact same code is working in a different environment, so it might be related to plesk.

Comment: Do you have other methods to test a connection to plesk? Maybe this clinet has a network issue and it isn't timing out properly.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but this code is actually run locally on plesk. I can also connect to the server with SSH and then connect to the dB with psql. Not sure how I could modify the timeout settings tho